# Python 3. Input in if else statements

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, input

[image: Problem image]

I am using string in if-else statement from input but not getting any result.

Comment: `is` checks for object identity. You should be using `==`. You also put in  `write` but you're checking against `writes`....

Answer (score 0):

Two issues appear when I see that:

You use the `is` operator, which checks if two variables refer to the same object. `x is y` is only true if one was defined as equal to the other. Instead, you should use the `==` operator to check if two string are equal. Also, you type *write*, not *writes*, whereas your program is checking for *writes*. Entering the correct string and using the `==` operator instead of `is` should fix your problems.

Comment: thanks it worked. But 'is' operator worked for no.s. Why not for strings?

Comment: @harsh As Neil stated, the `is` operater checks if they are the **same object** and so for strings to happen the same behavior you would need to define them as the same as the other..`x = y = "str"` then `is` would return true.